# How to bypass the user confirmation when installing packages on linux

Tags: bash

I'm writing a basic script in bash to automatically install a few packages on new machines (basically, the first script to run on a new machine before doing anything else). I'm downloading openssh-server and python for example.

My goal is just to launch the script in sudo mode, wait a few minutes and get started. The only problem I'm facing is the machine requires the user to input "y" when needed and I can't find a way to bypass this.

This is just a sample of my script :

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt update
sudo apt install openssh-server
sudo apt-get install python3
```

what I expect is just run this command and let it roll without the user to have and put "y" when needed

```
sudo bash start-script.sh
```

Comment: `apt-get` has an option to automatically reply yes to prompts. Lookup `-y` in https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get

Comment: so I just need to do apt -y install openssh-server @Inian ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the -y option of apt-get. From the apt-get man page:

```
   -y, --yes, --assume-yes
       Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
       run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
       changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
       package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will
       abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.
```